# Is it possible to use npm to run scripts in multiple subfolders?

Tags: npm

I have a folder (a project) with 3 subfolders (client, server, assets). Each subfolder has a different command to start and to work on the project I need to start the 3 apps. This is the folder layout and the commands I use to start each subproject:

> - project
>
>   - client (ionic serve)
>   - server (node index)
>   - assets (http-server -p 8082)

Currently, I go to each of the three folders and start each of the apps. To make the process more standard, each subproject has a package.json with a start script, so I just `cd subfolder && npm start`.

**My question:** is it possible to use npm on the parent folder (i.e., write a `package.json` there) in such a way that I can just run the following command and have the same (or similar) effect?

> project> npm start

I have tried using the package `parallelshell`, but it didnt work (probably because of the `cd`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "parallelshell 'cd app && ionic serve' 'cd api && npm start' 'cd assets && npm start'",
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to accomplish this. So you would create a `package.json` which looks something like the following:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "client": "cd client && npm start",
  "server": "cd server && npm start",
  "assets": "cd assets && ionic serve",
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\" \"npm run assets\" ",
},
...
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^1.0.0"
}
...
```

**Note**: This will start all three processes concurrently which means that you get mixed output of all three (like [@topheman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32790513/327074) already mentioned)

Comment: Thanks, a little fix `"start": "concurrent`  -> `"start": "concurrently`

Comment: As a late comment, but an alternative nonetheless, I would like to mention `npm-run-all` (https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/). I haven't used `concurrently` at all and can unfortunately not give neither opinion nor recommendation. Maybe someone else could enlighten us?

Comment: @dbm `npm-run-all` runs serial by default, but can also be parallel with `--parallel`. It *seems* that `npm-run-all` is a simpler system, where as `concurrently` has a lot more options for a more complex system setup.

Answer (score 70):

it is really late to answer but you got built-in option `--prefix`,
example:

```
-package.json
-/dist/ssr/package.json
```

```
# package.json in root
npm run start --prefix dist/ssr
```

Comment: ps: use --cwd in yarn

Comment: How would I run this command on multiple folders at the same time?  Let's say that I have, in addition to the aforementioned folder, another one in the path `-/dist/xyz/package.json`

Comment: my advice was for one command each. If you would like to use it as multiple, you have to deal with daemon command starts a multiple lines. Or just use docker and traefik for example

Comment: This is great, and I confirmed it worked although I cannot find any documentation on it via https://docs.npmjs.com/. @darksoulsong - here's a npm script example that uses the Concurrently package to run commands concurrently:
```
"scripts": {
  "back:dev": "npm run start --prefix back",
  "front:dev": "npm run dev --prefix front",
  "start": "npx concurrently \"npm:back:dev\" \"npm:front:dev\""
},
```

Comment: `--prefix` is an undocumented and unsupported feature which best is to try avoid using it

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that **all your three scripts** are **server launching-like** script task, which means that they're not like a build task (for example) that runs for 10s and stop the process.

**For each one of them, you launch them**, and **the process continues indefinitly**.

You could launch all of them in a **daemon way** with something like `forever`, but in your case, you are in dev mode (so **you want all the logs**, and **you don't want the errors** from the nodejs server **mixed** with the ionic one ...).

In case you don't mind about mixing logs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever (I assume this does nearly the same thing as parallelshell ...)