# Node: run npm server and proxy in different folders with one command?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, proxy, angular-cli

We currently have a project with a `server` folder and a `client` folder.

To run the project we have to cd to `server` folder, type `npm run nodemon` then, in a new Terminal tab/window, switch to the `client` folder and run `npm run proxy`.

The second command is a script in package.json:
`"proxy": "ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss -o --hmr -e=hmr --proxy-config proxy.config.json",`

So, how do I create one script in package.json to do both?  I realize how to run scripts in parallel, but the odd part here is the 2 scripts in different directories.  And different terminal windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple NPM scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: that doesn't really deal with running in different folders.  perhaps i should run a script a the root?

Comment: There are probably questions that suit the case better. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893546/3731501 . And yes, if `server` and `client` are siblings, it's a good thing to set up a separate project on their parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this script command and let me know its working:

```
"scripts": {
       "proxy": "(cd ../path/to/server && npm run nodemon) && (ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss -o --hmr -e=hmr --proxy-config proxy.config.json)",    
    }
```

Comment: currently, there's no package.json at the root.  the main package.json with the scripts and node modules is in `/client`.  But, yes, `/client` and `/server` are siblings in the root folder.

Comment: that starts the server, but then it seems the second command does not run.  `(cd ../server && npm run nodemon) && (ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss -o --hmr -e=hmr --proxy-config proxy.config.json)`

Comment: `|` replaced command working without any problem, by starting both the server?

Comment: Apparently.  The browser opens, running the project.